# Configure second content filter with Amavis

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

Is it possible to use a second content filter with Amavis?

I have a standard postfix+Amavis Ubuntu setup, but after spam filtering, I am wanting to run it through a second one to encrypt the message body - this bit works fine, however, I cant see a way of setting up Postfix to use multiple content filters, or a way for Amavis to then push it through a second filter.

The second filter uses a pipe:

`emailcrypt    unix    -       n       n       -       -       pipe
        flags= user=cryptuser argv=/usr/local/bin/emailcrypt.py`

which then bounces back in here:

`127.0.0.1:10099 inet    n       -       n       -       10      smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8`

So, I guess I am being dumb or something.. :)

If someone could help me out I would appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the first `content_filter` (i.e amavis ) in your `main.cf` file

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
#...
content_filter = smtp:[localhost]:10097
#...
```

or `master.cf` file.

```
#/etc/postfix/master.cf
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=smtp:[localhost]:10097
```

You will anyway define another `smtpd` server to receive the email from amavis. Specify your second content_filter there like

```
#/etc/postfix/master.cf
127.0.0.1:10098     inet    n   -   n   -    10      smtpd 
      -o content_filter=emailcrypt:dummy
# other options if any
```

Now the second filter can inject the mail back to the `smtpd` server listening on `10099`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Fantastic! Worked a treat. Thanks very much! :)